# Are there actually any reactions during which STATIC equilibrium is reached, as opposed to dynamic?

Tags: equilibrium

Static would be where a set amount of both products and reactants is formed. Dynamic would be where both the forward and backward reactions occur at equal rates, meaning no change in the overall product and reactant concentrations.